# Testing in async functions. Test passing when should be failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

Hi y'all this test should be failing but it passes while also throwing Assertion error.

```
 describe('Testing getAllrecipes',()=>{
  it('1. Test get All Recipes',(done)=>{
    var uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    var dbname = "testRecipes";
    var collectionName = "testCollectionClean";
    let driver = new MongoDriver(uri,dbname,collectionName);
    driver.dropCollection(); //Clean collection for testing... NEVER CALL ON PRODUCTION COLLECTION
    driver.addMockData();

    driver.getAllRecipe().then((promise)=>{
        assert.deepEqual(promise,'fake news')
        done();
    }).catch((e)=>{
        console.log(e);
        done();
    });
 });
})
```

CONSOLE:

```
AssertionError: expected [] to deeply equal 'fake news'
{
showDiff: true,
actual: [],
expected: 'fake news'
}
✓ 1. Test get All Recipes
    
8 passing (60ms)
```

How do I get the test to return a fail?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `catch` clause, you need to call `done` with the error,

```
    }).catch((e)=>{
        console.log(e);
        done(e);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks my guy! This worked! Is there anyway to have the test fail without a catch block?

Comment: Depending on your version of mocha/chai, you can just return the promise without the catch block, and it'll handle catching the error itself.

Comment: Thanks @Shadab again. Could you be more specific about what promise I would return? Would I return  driver.getAllRecipe().then(.......

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who's looking for this answer. Shadab was correct I needed to call done(e). My final solution looks like

```
return driver.getAllRecipe().then((promise)=>{
        assert.deepEqual(promise,'fake news')
    }).catch((e)=>{
        console.log(e);
        done(e);
        
    });
```